# Strange Recursive code to draw chart

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a hard time figuring out this piece of code marked in bold. Can some explain me those lines please

```
function growBars() {
    var barStartX = 0;
    var barStartY = 0;
    var barHeight = 0;
    var barValue = 0;

    <!-- ********** Start Unable to understand -->
    barValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
    barHeight = (barValue * chartHeight / maxValue) / numSteps * idxStep;
    barStartX = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + (i * (barWidth + barMargin)) + barMargin;
    barStartY = chartMargin + (chartHeight - barHeight);
    drawBar(barStartX, barStartY, barWidth, barHeight);
}
if (idxStep < numSteps) {
    idxStep++;
    setTimeout('growBars()', growSpeed);
}
} < -- * * * * * * * * * * * * * End till here-- >

function drawBar(barX, barY, barW, barH) {
    context.fillStyle = '#00c';
    context.fillRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
    context.shadowOffsetX = 3;
    context.shadowOffsetY = -3;
    context.shadowBlur = 3;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(200, 200, 200, .3)';
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
}
```

As you can see the above code draws bars on a graph. What I am unable to understand is the way this recursive function is used. What does that piece of code do?

Comment: If you fix your indentation, I think you'll find it's not recursive.

Comment: There's an extra `}` in there; I assume that's a typo.

Comment: What recursive function? Do you mean drawBar? I'm not sure you understand what 'recursive' means...

Comment: ok what does growBars() do inside the function whose name is also growBars(). I am kinda new to this, so please be gentle

Comment: @user1089173 It's **not** inside that function.

Comment: ok assuming nothing's recurive, what does that piece of code do?

Comment: We're not judgemental and are here to help, what it is doing is setting a timeout to growbars, calling it after a certein amount of miliseconds (growSpeed) has passed. This is likely to create some sort of animation and is not what the term 'recursion' is used for normally

Comment: that helped a little. Can you explain step by step how this works?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. barValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
2. barHeight = (barValue * chartHeight / maxValue) / numSteps * idxStep;
3. barStartX = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + (i * (barWidth + barMargin)) + barMargin;
4. barStartY = chartMargin + (chartHeight-barHeight);
5. drawBar(barStartX, barStartY, barWidth, barHeight);
```

1. Converts chartData.bars[i].value to integer
2. sets the bar height; Im not sure what numSteps or idxStep is
   3/4. sets bar x,y start coords
3. calls the drawBar function with the values calculated above.

Its not recursive although you don't need the recall to the function unless you plan on your graph illustrating a growth in the data

```
function growBars() { //START OF FUNCTION
    var barStartX = 0;
    var barStartY = 0;
    var barHeight = 0;
    var barValue = 0;

    <!-- ********** Start Unable to understand -->
    barValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
    barHeight = (barValue * chartHeight / maxValue) / numSteps * idxStep;
    barStartX = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + (i * (barWidth + barMargin)) + barMargin;
    barStartY = chartMargin + (chartHeight - barHeight);
    drawBar(barStartX, barStartY, barWidth, barHeight);
} //END OF FUNCTION
if (idxStep < numSteps) { //START OF IF STATEMENT
    idxStep++;
    setTimeout('growBars()', growSpeed);
} //END OF IF STATEMENT
} < -- * * * * * * * * * * * * * End till here-- > // UNPAIRED CLOSE BRACKET

function drawBar(barX, barY, barW, barH) {
    context.fillStyle = '#00c';
    context.fillRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
    context.shadowOffsetX = 3;
    context.shadowOffsetY = -3;
    context.shadowBlur = 3;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(200, 200, 200, .3)';
    context.strokeStyle = '#000';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
}
```

as you can see from my comments, the growbars is not called from within itself thus it is not recursive